# How to extract url/links that are contents of a webpage with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So the website I am using is : `https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html` and I want to extract all the social media links on the webpage.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html')
soup = bs(r.content)

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'socials'})

actual_links = [link['href'] for link in links]
```

I get an error, specifically:

> `KeyError: 'href'`

For a different example and webpage, I was able to use the same code to extract the webpage link but for some reason this time it is not working and I don't know why.

I also tried to see what the problem was specifically and it appears that
`links` is a nested array where `links[0]` outputs the entire content of the `ul` tag that has `class=socials` so its not iterable so to speak since the first element contains all the links rather than having each social `li` tag be seperate elements inside `links`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution using css selectors:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

links = soup.select('ul.socials li a')

actual_links = [link['href'] for link in links]

print(actual_links)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.instagram.com/keithgalli/', 'https://twitter.com/keithgalli', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/keithgalli/', 'https://www.tiktok.com/@keithgalli']
```

Comment: i even tried the css method where i use soup.select('ul.socials a') and didnt work but i didnt know the difference lied in the selector path ie. 'ul.socials li a'

Comment: According to css selectors, Firstly I select  tag ul(unorder list with  it's class name put dot before class  then next tag name (li)  with space then next tag a with space.  You also missed  parser to pull dom like xlml, html.parser . Here i used lxml . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://keithgalli.github.io/web- 
scraping/webpage.html')
soup = bs(r.content)

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'socials'})

actual_links = [link['href'] for link in links if 'href' in link.keys()]
```

After gaining some new information from you and visiting the webpage, I've realized that you did the following mistake:

[image]

The **socials** class is never used in any **a-element** and thus you won't find any such in your script. Instead you should look for the **li-elements** with the class **"social"**.

Thus your code should look like:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://keithgalli.github.io/web- 
scraping/webpage.html')
soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")

link_list_items = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'social'})
links = [item.find('a').get('href') for item in link_list_items]

print(links)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @GirthyLampost so do you have **NoneType** objects in the list you're iterating? (links)

Comment: No I shouldnt because i used find_all method to get the sub-content that only contains the href links I am interested in

Comment: @GirthyLampost OK - I've run your code and have found your error. I'll edit my post.

Comment: so i did a little investigating. i tried to extract just one specific link, the instagram one so i isolated it:  insta = soup.find('li', {'class':'social instagram'}) and then I tried to get the href and it returns None

Comment: @GirthyLampost you've used the wrong search-criteria. Check the post-update.

Comment: thank u all so much. this was definitely an elementary mistake so it might sound like a bad question but it caused a world of confusion for me as it is my first time trying to learn bs4 and web scraping. thanks again for ur patience.